# Getting 404 in the Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter

I have directory called "api" and in that I want to run a php script called "tweet.php". This script file is calling inside a JS file. However I am getting a 404. Need help to solve the issue.

Link to the project directory
http://yrolonline.com/mak_nutrition/

Thanks

Comment: to "need help" is not a question. please edit the question and suply all the details of what exactly you are trying to do, add relevant code snippets, and what are the expected results and what actually happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not good idea - create many enter points. Open Web Inspector and check your URL which using in JS code.

But much better use the default `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )` to creates path which should be used in Java Script.

Comment: Got it working. Thanks +1. Glad you answered the question